# Why is periodic harmonic analysis only possible with sines?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, alternative-proof

[This paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-057-03/S0002-9947-1945-0012158-8/S0002-9947-1945-0012158-8.pdf) shows that if we consider odd functions on $(-\pi,\pi)$ in $L_2$, then the only $2\pi$-periodic function $f$ for which $f(nx)$ is a complete orthogonal system is the sine function.

I'll loosely interpret this as saying that the conventional periodic harmonic analysis is only possible with sines, which is very non-intuitive. Why can't I use the square waveform, or the triangle waveform, or some smooth waveform (similar to sine but different) as a basis for harmonic decomposition?

Sure, that paper gives a proof. But their proof is a proof by exclusion. They don't use any properties of sines except that sines form a complete system. They essentially prove that there can only be one complete system of this form, and since we already know that sines are complete, that precludes other such systems from existence.

But that proof doesn't explain **why** is the sine so special; what's the unique property that only it has? Put another way, if I were Fourier, how would I know to consider sines, except by trial and error? Is it possible to **derive** this waveform from the fact that $f(nx)$ is orthogonal and complete in the space of odd functions on $(-\pi,\pi)$?

**Update.** Thanks for the historic background, but this question is more concerned with math than history. Namely, how one can "compute" $\sin x$ as the only $2\pi$-periodic $f$ for which $f(nx)$ is orthogonal and complete in the space of odd $L_2$ functions on $(-\pi,\pi)$. Not how one might guess the answer, or how one particular Jean-Baptiste Joseph Fourier guessed it.

Comment: The idea was that many problems in PDE involved the Laplacian, for which sine and cosine are eigenfunctions. Since they are eigenfunctions, they are easy to analyze. He hoped that they were actually a basis but he had no way to know for sure. At the time, analysis was still very much in its infancy. Calculus was still being formalized at the time so most advancements were done at the expense of rigor. Fourier was actually mocked and ostracized a bit by rigorous mathematicians for his series.

Comment: I might not know the history correctly, but I think perhaps Fourier was looking for solutions to the heat equation, and guessed that there should be separable solutions, and plugging in solutions of this separable form he found solutions involving sine and cosine (and sums thereof).  He then made the leap (or so I was told) of guessing that "any" function could be written as a linear combination of sines and cosines, which would allow him to solve the heat equation for arbitrary initial values.  A completely different viewpoint is to search for eigenfunctions of the shift operator.

Comment: First you write, "Put another way, if I were Fourier, how would I know to consider sines, except by trial and error?" And then you write, "Thanks for the historic background, but this question is more concerned with math than history." You want to know how Fourier would come up with this, but you don't want history ... hmmmmm. If you want to know how Fourier came up with all this, you can read translations of his *Treatise on Heat Conduction*; it's available on google books for free.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that orthogonal means nothing if you do not specify the scalar product (norm) you're using to define it. There are other sets of functions that are orthogonal and complete but they are so under different norms. Sine and cosine are only special in a Hilbert Space where the norm is the one defined by Fourier.

Comment: The question assumes $L_2$. Excuse me for not spelling out all the details; you can find them in the paper.